# How to specify default glassfish-web.xml?

Tags: glassfish, default, glassfish-3, configuration-files, web.xml

I have a situation where I need to specify some properties in glassfish-web.xml (like
session-properties & cookie-properties) that needs to be applied to all web application that are deployed under that domain.

One option is to create glassfish-web.xml per web-application. This is fine if there are only a few web applications on a domain.

However as these properties are common across all web applications I am wondering if there is a way to specify these configuration at glassfish server domain level (like default-web.xml) that are applied to every web application deployed.

Comment: I have done this before in `domain.xml`. Something like `<config name="server-config"><system-property></system-property>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glassfish 3+, put the configurations desired in `[GF_HOME]/domains/[yourdomain]/config/default-web.xml`

Take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beagc/index.html